# What does a fat arrow function followed by a closure do?

Tags: javascript

I just came across this code:

```
routes: routes.map(route => ({
```

Notice the arrow function being followed by a closure. Why are closures used here?

see this repo for reference: https://github.com/prograhammer/vue-pizza/blob/master/src/http/router.js#L33

Comment: that's not a closure. It's just the start of an object literal. The arrow function returns the object.

Comment: It is impossible to tell whether a function is a closure or not without seeing both the body of the function and the surrounding context. Also, what do you mean by "the arrow function followed by a closure"? You don't even show the arrow function, let alone what follows the arrow function, so how can we tell you something about what follows it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an object. The parenthesis is to denote that this is an object not a block.

`() => {return {hello: 'world' } } === () => ({hello: 'world'})`